# Of at most how many cubes is the figure built?

Tags: geometry

The following three pictures show a body which is built from equal cubes, seen from above (leftmost picture), front (the middle picture) and from the right (the rightmost picture).

Of at most how many cubes can the body be built?

(A) 18

(B) 19

(C) 20

(D) 21

(E) 22

I would say 21 but I cannot give a clear answer. I tried to recognize the width, length and height from the pictures.

**Edit:** Taking the hints in the comments into consideration, I get that the answer is (B).

[image: A body built from equal cubes seen from above, front and the right.]

Comment: Take the leftmost diagram, showing the top, and using the middle diagram, write in the maximum number that could be in each column: The middle $7$ squares would contain a $3$, while the outer $2$ squares would contain a $1$. Then use the rightmost diagram to reduce some of those numbers: The third row can contain at most a $2$, and the last row can contain at most a $1$. What are you left with?

Comment: From the left and middle picture I get at most 23 cubes. Is that correct?

Comment: And then I need to subtract 3, i.e. at most 20 in total.

Comment: Well, yes (ETA: referring to the left and middle diagram yielding a maximum of $23$), but some of those numbers have to be reduced by the rightmost diagram.

Comment: I get 20 in total.

Comment: The answer is not $20$. Take a little more care; you have to reduce the number in three of the columns, but the amount of the reduction is not $3$.

Comment: @BrianTung I now get at most 19 cubes. Correct?

Comment: Yes, I thinks so.